# harris detector in callback

Tags: opencv, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to implement Harris corner detector. But the result are pretty skewed. There is always some symmetry in the detected corners as shown in the image below which definitely is not true.(right image is grayscaled image...why does it happens as such..must be 3 different channels joined together..

[harris detection on terrain http://s22.postimg.org/mbaa8fua5/frame0001.jpg](http://s22.postimg.org/mbaa8fua5/frame0001.jpg)
[harris detection on terrain http://s17.postimg.org/ugpmryg0b/frame0000.jpg](http://s17.postimg.org/ugpmryg0b/frame0000.jpg)

My callback portion looks like:

```
void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& image)
{
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;

    try                         
    {
        cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(image, enc::BGR8); 
   
    }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
    {
        ROS_ERROR("Conversion error: %s", e.what());
        return;
    }

    cv::Mat image_gray, image_corner, image_norm, image_scaled;
    
    cv::cvtColor(cv_ptr->image, image_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY); 
    cv::cornerHarris(image_gray, image_corner,blockSize, apertureSize, k, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT);    
    
 
    cv::normalize(image_corner, image_norm, 0, 255, cv::NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1, cv::Mat());   
    cv::convertScaleAbs (image_norm, image_scaled); //scaled
    
    

    //Drawing circles around corner
    
    for(int j=0; j<cv_ptr->image.rows ; j++) //norm
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<cv_ptr->image.cols; i++)
        {
            if((int) image_scaled.at<float>(j,i) > thresh)
            {
                cv::circle(cv_ptr->image, cv::Point(i, j),2,CV_RGB(255,0,0)); //scaled
            }
        }
    }

    pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());     

}
```

I think it is basically due to the RGB channels but there are four similar clusters of corner which confused me. most of the code is directly taken from opencv example of harris detector.
Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90506/harris-detector-in-callback/) by [espee](https://answers.ros.org/users/6531/espee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2013-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You use CV_8UC1 in normalize(). Because of this image_norm should be CV_8UC1 and image_scaled should be CV_8UC1, too.
But you use image_scaled.at !

A good practice is do use the Wrapper Mat_ image_scaled. Because:

1. You can use a shorter method to access the elements (image_scaled(j,i))
2. The types can be tested at compile time.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [espee](https://answers.ros.org/users/6531/espee/) on 2013-10-14**:
Thanks. Actually I got is solved by changing  to . Could you please write a snippet of  code for the wrapper? I tried w/o success.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-10-16**:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id7
this should help

**Comment by [espee](https://answers.ros.org/users/6531/espee/) on 2013-10-21**:
Thanks for the link...